# Date Time Values Rearragement

Tags: pandas, date, time, pivot, transpose

Hi I have a data frame df with the following columns and so on the values are for the whole month.

```
    Timestamp               Count
0   2017-10-01 00:00:00     783
1   2017-10-01 01:00:00     662
2   2017-10-01 02:00:00     075
3   2017-10-01 03:00:00     272
4   2017-10-01 04:00:00     381
```

I want to put the values in the order of row wise per hour basis

Output required

```
       Hour1   Hour2    Hour3 ......... Hour24
Day1   783     662       075  .........
Day2   ...................................
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) by `Timestamp` converted to [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html), last add [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (pd.pivot(df['Timestamp'].dt.date, 
              df['Timestamp'].dt.hour + 1, 
              df['Count'])
        .add_prefix('Hour')
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Alternative is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index([df['Timestamp'].dt.date, df['Timestamp'].dt.hour + 1])['Count']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('Hour')
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df)
            Hour1  Hour2  Hour3  Hour4  Hour5
2017-10-01    783    662     75    272    381
```